# What is the projection of V onto U along W?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help with this definition: given a vector space $V$, what is exactly the projection of $V$ onto $U$ along $W$, where $U$, $W$ are subspaces of $V$ s.t. $V$ = $U$ ⨁ $W$? I know what the projection of a vector onto a subspace (or onto another vector) is, but I couldn't find no information about this third 'type' of projection.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> Is there a condition that $V$ is the direct sum of $U$ and $W$?

Comment: Yes, there is this exact condition!

Answer (score 3):

Because $V = U \oplus W$, every vector $v$ in $V$ may be written *uniquely* in the form $v = u + w$ with $u$ in $U$ and $w$ in $W$. Projection from $V$ to $U$ is defined by $\operatorname{proj}_{U}(v) = u$.

[image: Projection from a vector space onto a subspace]